# Join arrays of objects on a mutiple key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, join

I have two arrays of objects:

```
A = [
    { id1: "1", id2: "a", p1: "3", p2: "4" },
    { id1: "1", id2: "b", p1: "5", p2: "6" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "a", p1: "7", p2: "8" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "b", p1: "9", p2: "10" }
];


B = [
    { id1: "1", id2: "a", p3: "13", p4: "14" },
    { id1: "1", id2: "b", p3: "15", p4: "16" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "a", p3: "17", p4: "18" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "b", p3: "19", p4: "20" }
];
```

I need a function that makes an inner join between the two objects based on the two properties `id1` and `id2`, making a union of the other properties (*properties names are never equal except for `id1` and `id2`*)
In other words I need as a result:

```
C = [
    { id1: "1", id2: "a", p1: "3", p2: "4", p3: "13", p4: "14" },
    { id1: "1", id2: "b", p1: "5", p2: "6", p3: "15", p4: "16" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "a", p1: "7", p2: "8", p3: "17", p4: "18" },
    { id1: "2", id2: "b", p1: "9", p2: "10", p3: "19", p4: "20" }
];
```

In here I can find a way to make the join using one single key.
I need an extention for the multiple keys case.

http://learnjsdata.com/combine_data.html

Comment: What part of extending this code are you having trouble with?

Comment: Could you make sure you Object literals are valid,..  It helps others help you.

Comment: Amended. Sotry about that. The provided code works fine for a single key only. I need to extend it for the mutliple keys case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both provided answers **DO NOT** deliver expected result (**inner join** which is supposed to contain **only** matching items from both data sets).

I have somewhat extended input arrays in order to demonstrate the difference of output for provided answers and mine:

```js
const A = [
 {id1:"1", id2:"a", p1:"3", p2:"4"},
 {id1:"1", id2:"b", p1:"5", p2:"6"},
 {id1:"2", id2:"a", p1:"7", p2:"8"},
 {id1:"2", id2:"b", p1:"9", p2:"10"},
 {id1:"3", id2:"c", p1:"1", p2:"3"}
];

const B = [
 {id1:"1", id2:"a", p3:"13", p4:"14"},
 {id1:"1", id2:"b", p3:"15", p4:"16"},
 {id1:"2", id2:"a", p3:"17", p4:"18"},
 {id1:"2", id2:"b", p3:"19", p4:"20"},
 {id1:"4", id2:"k", p3:"11", p4:"13"}
];

const innerJoined = A.reduce((result, itemA) => {
  const itemB = B.find(itemB => itemB.id1 == itemA.id1 && itemB.id2 == itemA.id2);
  if(itemB) result.push({...itemA, ...itemB});
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(innerJoined);
```

Comment: You're quite welcome. I must admit I didn't put enough effort into my answer yesterday as I was in a hurry to get out of the office. Today I've fixed my code, it is way more neat now and works noticeably [faster](https://jsperf.com/arrays-inner-joined), than accepted answer.

Comment: `noticeably faster`  That was an interesting result, in theory using a object hash lookup should give better results.  But I've a feeling it's the creating of the lookup key that's slowing this down.  Array.find has a time complexity of O(n), but it looks like Javascript is so fast nowadays it's hardly a thing.. :)   ps, I've made your code into a snippet, it's just nicer.  Instead of clicking `{}` icon, click the `<>` instead.

Comment: My guess is that my code is faster due to usage of `some()` and `find()` as both are stopping to iterate over target array upon first match. Thanks for turning my code into executable snippet, I've edited my post from mobile, couldn't use that feature

Comment: @user11299053 How would you modifiy your code to have a outer join instead?

Comment: @MauroGentile: I guess, that would be something, like [that](https://codepen.io/sneakybastard/pen/WWYZPe?editors=0012)

Comment: @MauroGentile you should test on more than one browser. This code is 40% slower when I run it on Safari - both desktop and iOS. It's essentially identical on Firefox. Additionally both arrays are very small. This code is O(n²) which means it is unlikely to perform well as the size of the arrays increase.

Comment: Please if you are going start an argument, learn how to calculate big O. The `reduce()` isn't nested; it is run outside the loop once making it O(2N) — 1 N to run the reduce to make a hash lookup, 1 N to run the other loop. Hash lookups are constant time O(1). This reduces to O(n). But it's all a silly argument — neither is *"noticeably faster"*. You're talking the difference between 70K and 63K operations/second — that's *measurably* faster with a tiny array. If it was noticeably faster you wouldn't need jsPerf.

Comment: Incidentally [here's the test with large arrays](https://jsperf.com/reducehas-or-find/1) just to demonstrate the difference between O(n) and O(n²). I *would* call that a noticeable difference, but I still don't think it matters (unless you really do have large arrays).

Comment: @MarkMeyer: looks like you're right, your code really has a chance to perform 40% faster in 13 cases out of 100 (when user happen to run Safari).

Comment: @MarkMeyer: I just wonder, what if in your test random keys  duplicating statistically 10 times will produce duplicating paired keys (which is not the case for OP scenario), thus reducing the size of lookup array,  raise certain suspicion?

Comment: Maybe @user11299053, but I don't think you can get around the fact that for every item in array A you need to search through array B. It searches through B over and over. V8 does some amazing optimizations, but it can only do so much as N grows. Unless there's something peculiar about the data that allows `find` to locate the record in less than linear time on average, the time it takes will grow quadratically with N. Here's a test with only 2500 unique, shuffled items: https://jsperf.com/hashvfind-ii/1

Comment: I would say, you don't need nothing peculiar, e.g. having array B much bigger than array A, and id properties ordered within array B would set your code in a very uncomfortable position. So, I admit there could be circumstances where one  could be faster than another. However, nothing can change the fact that my code is more compact.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a lookup based on one array with a composite key from the two ids, then loop through the second, look up the merged key, and create a new object from the two items using `Object.assign()`. This will allow you to make the list without having an O(n²) solution of searching `A` for every item in `B`

```js
let A=[
    {id1:"1", id2:"a", p1:"3", p2:"4"},
    {id1:"1", id2:"b", p1:"5", p2:"6"},
    {id1:"2", id2:"a", p1:"7", p2:"8"},
    {id1:"2", id2:"b", p1:"9", p2:"10"}
]

let B=[{id1:"1", id2:"a", p3:"13", p4:"14"},
       {id1:"1", id2:"b", p3:"15", p4:"16"},
       {id1:"2", id2:"a", p3:"17", p4:"18"},
       {id1:"2", id2:"b", p3:"19", p4:"20"}
]
  
let lookup = A.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[`${item.id1}_${item.id2}`] = item // key in form of id1_id2
  return obj
}, {})

let merged = B.reduce((arr, item) => {
  if (lookup[`${item.id1}_${item.id2}`]) {
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, lookup[`${item.id1}_${item.id2}`], item))
  }
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(merged)
```

You just need to make sure the separator of the key (`_` here) doesn't exist in you ids. If that's a problem, you could make a nested object with lookups like `obj[id1][id2]`:

```
let lookup = A.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (!obj[item.id1]) obj[item.id1] = {}
    obj[item.id1][item.id2] = item
    return obj
}, {} )
```

and adjust the `reduce()` callback to fit.

Answer (score 2):

If the array's are very large, using a lookup like @MarkMeyer shows <s>would</s> **might** be better option.  But for smaller arrays doing a simple map, array spread & find works fine.

> As pointed out by @user11299053 this is not the equivalent of an inner
>   join, maybe a left join instead,.. So I'll leave this as is, it might
>   be useful. :)

```js
const A=[
  {id1:"1", id2:"a", p1:"3", p2:"4"},
  {id1:"1", id2:"b", p1:"5", p2:"6"},
  {id1:"2", id2:"a", p1:"7", p2:"8"},
  {id1:"2", id2:"b", p1:"9", p2:"10"}
];

const B=[
  {id1:"1", id2:"a", p3:"13", p4:"14"},
  {id1:"1", id2:"b", p3:"15", p4:"16"},
  {id1:"2", id2:"a", p3:"17", p4:"18"},
  {id1:"2", id2:"b", p3:"19", p4:"20"}
];
  
const merged = B.map(item => ({
  ...A.find(
    f => f.id1 === item.id1 && f.id2 === item.id2),
  ...item
}));

console.log(merged);
```